# Who are "tag followers"?

Tags: support, tags

People that have the tag in their "favourites", or maybe those who have subscribed to the RSS feed?

Comment: Note: this mechanism went over a full overhaul, changing it drastically. The answer to this question is now in the duplicate that introduced the change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can tell, it's the number of people who have favorited the tag plus the number of e-mail subscribers.

People who both favorite and subscribe seem to count twice.

Comment: "Clicked the star to highlight [the tag]"? How can you do that?

Comment: @Mada Hover over a tag, then click the star that appears in the pop-up. Although I removed that part because I remembered it's not the only way to favorite a tag.

Comment: Amazing! I thought the only method to "favourite" a tag is to type it by hand in the question list view. Thanks!

Comment: @MaDa FYI, it has changed drastically, see the dupe for details.